# Q: dart/flutter MAP 'insertAll' method

Tags: flutter, dart, logic

I need to modify existing Map by inserting items from the first index and shifts all later objects towards the end of the list.

My existing Map is more or less like this :

```
{0: {year:2022,month:11,day:1}}
{1: {year:2022,month:11,day:2}}
{2: {year:2022,month:11,day:3}}
```

And i need to insert some values to the first index and modify the existing index like this:

```
{0: {year:2022,month:8,day:1}} //Add this
{1: {year:2022,month:8,day:2}} //Add this
{2: {year:2022,month:8,day:3}} //Add this
{3: {year:2022,month:11,day:1}}
{4: {year:2022,month:11,day:2}}
{5: {year:2022,month:11,day:3}}
```

My code is like this :

```
void main() {
  var list = [
    {0:{'year':2022,'month':11,'day':1}},
    {1:{'year':2022,'month':11,'day':2}},
    {2:{'year':2022,'month':11,'day':3}},
  ];

  Map map = list.asMap();

  print(map.keys.toList());
     //result : [0, 1, 2]

  print(map.values.toList());
     //result : [{0: {year: 2022, month: 11, day: 1}}, {1: {year: 2022, month: 11, day: 2}}, {2: {year: 2022, month: 11, day: 3}}]
 
  
}
```

I want to add 3 row at first index, please help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the List and inside it a Map
List is an ordered list but, Map is not ordered list.

the index in List will generate automatically
try this code i hope it's what you are looking for

```
void main() {

  var listOfMap = [
    {"year":2022,"month":11,"day":1},
    {"year":2022,"month":11,"day":2},
    {"year":2022,"month":11,"day":3},
  ];

  print(listOfMap);
  
  // ex: inset in index number 0 the 
  // value of {"year": 2022, "month": 8, "day": 1})
  listOfMap.insert(0, {"year": 2022, "month": 8, "day": 1});
  listOfMap.insert(1, {"year": 2022, "month": 8, "day": 2});
  listOfMap.insert(2, {"year": 2022, "month": 8, "day": 3});

  print(listOfMap);
}
```

Comment: Hi Naser, thank you for your answer, but that's not answering my question, i have edit the question and add the code, please take a look, Thank you so much!